# I can't scrape the google search result with Chinese character keywords

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup, urlencode, chinese-locale

I can't perform the "chinese keywords"search here . (eng words are okay)

`String search = "大學";`

English keywords are fine here (able to do search )

I tried to use both `UTF-8` or `big5` for the `charset`.

But both of them are not working .

Here is my work .

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {

          String[] line = new String[100];
      final int[] score = {    0};


        String google = "http://www.google.com/search?q=";

        String search = "大學";

        String charset = "UTF-8";//UTF-8 is neither working 

        String news="&tbm=nws";

  String string = google + URLEncoder.encode(search , charset) + news+"&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2016%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2016";
     String userAgent ="Chrome/57.0.2987.133"; 
     int numberOfResultpages = 10; // grabs first two pages of search results
    int idx = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfResultpages; i++) {

       Document document = Jsoup.connect(string).userAgent(userAgent) .data("start",""+i).get();
    Elements links = document.select( ".r>a");

        for (Element link : links) {

            String title = link.text();
            String url = link.absUrl("href"); // Google returns URLs in format "http://www.google.com/url?q=<url>&sa=U&ei=<someKey>".
            url = URLDecoder.decode(url.substring(url.indexOf('=') + 1, url.indexOf('&')), "UTF-8");

            if (!url.startsWith("http")) {
                continue; // Ads/news/etc.
            }
            System.out.println("Title: " + title);
            System.out.println("URL: " + url);

            line[idx++]=title;
       // }

}
     }
```

Comment: try to use UTF-16 once.

Comment: @Santosh Hegde Not working .`search?q=%FE%FF%FF%FD%FF%FD%FF%FD%FF%FDj%FE%FF%FF%FD%FF%FD`  Search item become hex term

Comment: @Santosh Hegde UTF-16 make search results of eng keyword collapesd too